Dash boundary incorrect in parbox?
If I create a parbox in moderncv, the dashes are out, like:
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
\firstname{Foo}
\familyname{\textsc{Bar}}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\fbox{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{
    -- ooo\\
    \fbox{--} ooo\\
    -- Bar
  }}
\end{document}

produces:

What's wrong here? My goal was to insert this into a \cvline{foo}{bar} since \cvline{foo}{bar\\baz} produces an error.

it's using microtype so punctutation produdes, you could use \strut-- ooo

Yeah, I ended up \strut, thanks. Surprised to see this, is this a feature or a bug? ^^'

@DavidCarlisle if it's a feature, can I disable it globally?

Try \microtypesetup{protrusion=false}. You can find more settings in the manual of the microtype package.

@tobiasBora it's a feature (usually affecting the right margin) justified paragraphs can look ragged if they have lots of small punctuation characters ending lines so microtype adjusts things so punctuation slightly produdes into the margin giving usually an overall more solid look, but of course if you put a frame with zero padding around the text, then produding into the frame is not a good idea:-)

@jlab: Awesome, thanks a lot it works!
